# Can volume affect capacitance?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I know the math doesn't support it, but will a solid sphere and a thin foil, both of the same surface area, measure exactly the same capacitance?

Do electrons strictly gather on the surface (presumably owing to their mutual repulsion)?

At a certain thinness, say a deposited layer a couple of atoms deep, does the surface become a single surface rather than two surfaces, hence halving the effective surface area?

I know that's stated as three questions but really all the same fundamentally.

Comment: I don't think they are the same fundamentally. A sphere has a completely different geometry from a thin foil.

Comment: Let's then consider a cube vs foil instead of a sphere. Closely related topology of differing proportions.

Comment: Were you instead comparing a solid conducting sphere and a thin, hollow conducting sphere? (Bringing in the cube confused things even further.)

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  A hollow and solid sphere would be a fine comparison.  The question is whether the volume of a solid plays any role in capacitance.  In a thin foil it's easy enough to throw volume out of the thought process since it's so minimal.  So comparing a thin foil to a massive chunk of metal, regardless of specific shape, is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Perhaps explaining the practical application behind the question will help clarify further.  I'm making some large capacitive sensors, of up to maybe four or five square feet.  These are being timed with an RC to determine capacitance.  I'm trying to anticipate two things - 1) will my R/C timing be different with a 1/4" plate vs a thin foil and 2) will the current draw on my microprocessor pin increase with a thick plate.  And of course I want to understand the physics behind the practical answer.

Comment: Looks like I will need to resort to practical measurement -- what I should have done anyway:)